# Capistrano fails when trying to connect to remote db saying: rvm-shell no such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano

I have a capistrano recipe that is using a remote database in a Rails 3 application. Here is part of the recipe:

```
role :web, "ip1"
role :app, "ip1"
role :db,  "ip2"

set :rvm_type, :system
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.3'

set :deploy_to, "/apps/gits/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :deploy_env, 'production'
```

And capistrano is giving me this error: `usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell: No such file or directory`

But if I comment out the database server (which doesn't have rvm) and let rails think the db is on the web server (which does have rvm) everything works fine.

I'm assuming since :rvm_type is set to system capistrano is looking for it on the system, but why is it looking for it at all ? Is there any way around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rvm-capistrano does not support it yet, you would have to `set :default_shell` per server.

there is already a ticket for this feature https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano/issues/11